# Python - I have to reimport modules when treating a script as a module

Tags: python, module, python-import

I am importing a script as a module, for use in a main python script.

I'm finding that, for example, I would need to place `import matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt` at the top of the module script, even though this line has already been stated in the main python script.

Is there any way to avoid this re-importing and speed up the code?

Comment: what performance issue are you seeing with redundant importing?

Comment: The code is taking 41 seconds to run instead of the original 3 seconds... I initially thought this was due to redundant importing but it is obviously something else, even though the code has exactly the same contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not reimport already imported code, so even if you place `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in the main script as well as the other script, if the main script first imported it, it would not get re-imported in the other script , as it would notice that it has already been imported before.

Example to show this -

My a.py -

```
import c
import b
print("Inside A")
```

My b.py -

```
print("Inside B - Before Importing")
import c
print("Inside B - After Importing")
```

My c.py -

```
print("Inside C")
```

When I run `python a.py` , the result is -

```
Inside C
Inside B - Before Importing
Inside B - After Importing
Inside A
```

So if you are facing any performance issue, it must be something else, not re-importing of `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`